# How works the eleventh water breathing technique?

Tags: demon-slayer

In the last episode (20) you see Giyu Tomioka use an eleventh breath technique. He stopped the blood threates without doing anything. So how does it work? And it was said that there were only 10. So why didn't Tanjiro know about this?

Comment: As per I have read the manga, It's not yet revealed anywhere in there yet, about Giyu's 11th form.

Comment: @VishalTarkar ahh okay too bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *So how does it work?*

**Eleventh Style: Lull (拾じゅう壱いちノ型かた 凪なぎ Jū Ichi no kata: Nagi?)**

Giyu engages a skill that disables and nullifies incoming attacks. However, its effectiveness is limited as fast and numerous attacks can break through - [Link](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Giyu_Tomioka)

- *So why didn't Tanjiro know about this?*

Tanjiro doesnt know this because the 11th style is an original attack created by Giyu Tomioka but somewhere in the episode they said that every user can be able to have its own unique extra form.

Comment: I have replaced the link with correct one as one you have placed was not working. Also I wonder where this details are taken as in manga I don't read anywhere or it was mentioned.

Comment: It was written from the wiki, Giyu is one of the examples that learned another extra form there is still other breathing technique users that invented their own unique extra form e.g Zenitsu's *Seventh Style: Flaming Thunder God*.